# COM: Windows Media player API not working

Tags: c++, windows, com, dcom, wmp

I am learning to use **windows media player API** using **COM**. As, i am being a newbie to it,to get started i am just trying to call one of the function 
***get_fullScreen*** from ***IWMPPlayer4*** interface. This function returns Boolean value. I called this function at both times when media player is running and not running. But, every time this function returns false. I have also tried calling functions from different interfaces. It looks that, all API's are getting failed.

I am sharing my code snippet:

```
 #define STR_MEDIAPLAYER L"{6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6}"
 IID IID_IMediaPlayer;

IWMPPlayer4 *pIWmpPlayer4 = NULL;
int
main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    hr = IIDFromString(STR_MEDIAPLAYER, &IID_IMediaPlayer);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout<<"\n IIDFromString failed!";
    }

    hr = CoCreateInstance(
                        IID_IMediaPlayer, // 
                        NULL,
                        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                        IID_IWMPPlayer4,
                        (void**)&pIWmpPlayer4
                        );
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout<<"\n CoCreateInstance failed!";
    }


    hr = pIWmpPlayer4->get_fullScreen(&bFlag);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        cout<<"\n pIWmpControls failed!";
    }

    CoUninitialize();
     return 0;
}
```

Any help onto this is appreciable. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are creating your own player, you cannot see it.  If you want to connect to an existing player then you have to use IRunningObjectTable::GetObject()

Comment: Why did you expect it to return TRUE?

Comment: @selbie Basically what i am trying to do is test whether this function is working or not. If windows media player is running in background with full screen, then this function should return flag value as 'TRUE'. But in real, it is returning FALSE

Comment: @HansPassant Do i really need to use IRunningObjectTable::GetObject(). I read about it on msdn and its somewhat related to Imoniker. I am newbie to COM. I am not familiar to Moniker yet. Is there any another simple way?. I am implementing COM client.